# Create my own custom ellipsis bullet point

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-word-2010

I regularly use an ellipsis as a bullet point in a list of items in Word/Outlook 2010.
Example:
I like summer because...
... it's warm out.
... we go on vacation.
... my birthday is in July.

Currently in Word/Outlook if you type certain characters like a hyphen and hit space, it will automatically start a bulleted list using the hyphen.
I would really like the same functionality with the ellipsis.  When I type the third period and hit space, start a bulleted list.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  Registry hack?  Hidden Word Setting?

Comment: Sidenote: In Word, when you type the third period, Word's autocorrect converts the three periods to one ellipsis character. You can type the ellipsis using `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`.`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this by creating a style in Word 2010.

You define the bullet style as you would any other.

1. Pick your custom bullet and apply it to a paragraph along with what ever other formatting you want, ie indenting.
2. Display the Styles task pane
   a. make sure the cursor is in the para with the formatting for the new style, on the bottom of the style pane is there are 3 buttons, click on the left most one, New Style to display the Create New Style from Formatting dialog
   b. give your new style an appropriate name
   c. look at the check box options at the bottom of the dialog, make sure to select the New Documents based on this template option
   d.  click on OK to save your new style.

Comment: Hi @Dave Rook, Thanks for the response, unfortunately I don't think this answers the question.  _When I type the third period and hit space, start a bulleted list._  I know how to create the bullet, I was just hoping there was a way to automatically start the bulleted list by typing the ellipsis rather than having to go up and select it from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Auto Complete entry

In Word 2010, Go to File --> Options --> Proofing --> Auto Correct Options... --> Auto Correct [tab]

From there...

[image: AutoCorrect dialog box]

Enter the 3 `dots` in the first field and enter the bullet by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while typing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>

While this will change the ellipsis into a bullet, I don't know if it will start a bulleted list.  Word may get the gist though after an indent or two.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I think OP wants an automatic bulleted list with *ellipsis instead of regular bullets* (like the automatic hyphen bulleted list) **Edit:** After reading OP's comment regarding Dave Rook's answer, it looks your solution is what he wants.

Comment: @amiregelz, oh, well, you could be right :)  bulleted list with or without bullets as the bullets can get downright confusing :)

Comment: @amiregelz, your understanding was correct the first time.  I'm looking for a automatic bulleted list that uses an ellipsis as the "bullet point"